# Cannot POST /update-user

Tags: mongodb, syntax-error, ejs, crud

Having an issue with an application I am working on. By attempting to edit existing user data on a website forum, the message `Cannot POST /update-user` shows up.

Here is the update-user.ejs file:

```
 <!-- include header -->
<%- include('include/_header') %>
<!-- /include header -->

<!-- Main Site -->
<main id="site-main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box-nav d-flex justify-between">
      <div class="filter">
        <a href="/"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i> All Users</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-title text-center">
      <h2 class="text-dark">Update User</h2>
      <span class="text-light">Use the below form to Update an account</span>
    </div>

    <!-- add user form -->
    <!-- form handling -->
    <form method="POST" id="update_user">
      <div class="new_user">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name" class="text-light">Name</label>
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= user._id %>" />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value="<%= user.name %>"
            placeholder="Random Name"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Email" class="text-light">Email</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="email"
            value="<%= user.email%>"
            placeholder="example@gmail.com"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="gender" class="text-light">Gender</label>
          <div class="radio inline">
            <input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="gender" value="Male" <%=
            user.gender == 'Male' ? 'checked' : '' %>>
            <label for="radio-2" class="radio-label">Male</label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio inline">
            <input type="radio" id="radio-3" name="gender" value="Female" <%=
            user.gender == 'Female' ? 'checked' : '' %> >
            <label for="radio-3" class="radio-label">Female</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="gender" class="text-light">Status</label>
          <div class="radio inline">
            <input type="radio" id="radio-4" name="status" value="Active" <%=
            user.status == 'Active' ? 'checked' : '' %> >
            <label for="radio-4" class="radio-label">Active</label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio inline">
            <input type="radio" id="radio-5" name="status" value="Inactive" <%=
            user.status == 'Inactive' ? 'checked' : '' %> >
            <label for="radio-5" class="radio-label">Inactive</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn text-dark update">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</main>
<!-- /Main Site -->

<!-- include footer -->
<%- include('include/_footer') %>
<!-- /include footer -->
```

Also have this controller.js file

```
  var Userdb = require('../model/model');

//create and save new users
exports.create = (req, res) => {
    //validate request
    if (!req.body) {
        res.status(400).send({
            message: "User content can not be empty"
            
        });
        return;
    }

    //new user
    const user = new Userdb({
        name:req.body.name,
        email:req.body.email,
        gender:req.body.gender,
        status:req.body.status
    });

    //save user in the database
    user
    .save(user)
    .then(data=>{
        //res.send(data);
        res.redirect('/add-user')
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        res.status(500).send({message:err.message || "Error occured while creating a create operation" });
    });

};

//retrieve and return all users/retrieve and return a single user
exports.find =(req,res)=> {
    if(req.query.id)
    {
const id = req.query.id;

Userdb.findById(id)
.then(data =>{
if(!data){
    res.status(404).send({
        message:"User not found with id ${id}"+id
    });
}
else
{
    res.send(data);
}
});
    
}else{
        try{
            Userdb.find()
            .then(user=>{
                res.send(user);
            })
            .catch(err=>{
                res.status(500).send({message:err.message || "Error occured while retrieving user information"});
            });
        }
        finally{
            console.log("done");
        }
    }
    
};



//Update a new identified user by user id
exports.update = (req, res) => {
if(!req.body){
    return res.status(400).send({
        message:"data to update content can not be empty"
    });
    
}
const id = req.params.id;
Userdb.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body,{ useFindAndModify: false})
.then(data=>{
    
    if(!data){
        res.status(404).send({
            message:"User not found with id${id} "
        });
    }else
    {
        res.send(data);
    }
});
};

//Delete a user with specified user id in request
exports.delete = (req, res) => {
const id = req.params.id;
Userdb.findByIdAndDelete(id).then(data=>{
    if(!data){
        res.status(404).send({
            message:"Cannot delete with id${id} "
        });
    }else{
        res.send({message:"User deleted successfully"});
    }
});
};
```

Here is the model.js file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true
    },
    gender: String,
    status: String
});

const Userdb = mongoose.model('userbd',schema);

module.exports = Userdb;
```

and router.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const route = express.Router();

const services = require('../services/render');

const controller = require('../controller/controller');
/* @descript Root Route
@method GET/
*/
route.get('/',services.homeRoutes);

/* @descript add users
@method GET/ add-user
*/

route.get('/add-user', services.add_user); 
/* @descript update users
@method GET/ update-user
*/

route.get('/update-user', services.update_user);


//API
route.post('/api/users', controller.create);
route.get('/api/users', controller.find);
route.put('/api/users/:id', controller.update);
route.delete('/api/users/:id', controller.delete);

module.exports=route;
```

The database connects fine and I can add new users, but when attempting to edit existing users I get the POST message. Trying to narrow down exactly where and what the problem is. I am using MongoDB Atlas.

Answer (score 0):

in controller.js try this:

```js
module.exports.create = (req, res) => {
...
}
```

Short answer:
The module.exports is a special object which is included in every JavaScript file in the Node.js application by default. The module is a variable that represents the current module, and exports is an object that will be exposed as a module. So, whatever you assign to module.exports will be exposed as a module.

but for more information visit [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/nodejs-module-exports)

Comment: Explain how to solution fix the problem (and why)

Comment: Edited the controller.js section with no success: module.exports.update = (req, res) => {....}

Comment: I have added POST method to router file and the error goes away. The problem now is that it is not updating existing user information.

Comment: to update users, try a PUT request. Updating is different from adding data

Comment: Also, the logic will change to you should use findByIdAndUpdate learn more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mongoose-findbyidandupdate-function)